# Magento 2.3.1 - Cant Save Edits to Product. Nothing Happens

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

I am on Magento 2.3.1, with php 7.1

When I edit an existing product, and then click save. Nothing happens when I push save. Its like its not registering. I clicked the other save option (Save & Close), (Save & New), and still nothing happens!

This is happening on two seperate versions of Magento 2.3.1

Any ideas?

Comment: Any js errors in console logs? Looks like problem with javascript. Maybe you have to redeploy static content?

Comment: tried reploying static data 100000 times. Where can I check the console logs? I have checked all var/log errors and nothing about this. Because there is no error. Nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: It has something to do with the upgrade from 2.2. When I add a new product into 2.3, I can edit it. But I cant edit any products that have been already in the system since I had 2.2

Comment: When i try to edit new products I get this error: Warning: file_put_contents blic_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---0eb_REFLECTION): failed to open stream: Permission denied public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 693

Comment: I was talking about the browser console log. Open dev tools with F12 and check for any issues on "Console" tab

Comment: no errors in the console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things will made this.

1. Directory and File permission issue
2. Cache issue

> Warning: file_put_contents
>   blic_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---0eb_REFLECTION): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied
>   public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line
>   693

This error will come only when the directory has a permissions issue.

So Kindly set Magento recommended permissions to directories and files.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

find var pub/static pub/media  generated/ app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;

find var pub/static pub/media generated/ app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;

chown -R :<web server group> .

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

After run permission command you need to run below commands :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: ok. I am running these commands now. Do you think these error happen because I ran composer as root?

Comment: what is the <web server group> ?

Comment: did not work.....still cant save products...

Comment: Are you still got this error: Warning: file_put_contents blic_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---0eb_REFLECTION): failed to open stream: Permission denied public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 693

Comment: No, that permissions error has been fixed!

Comment: If I create a new product, I can edit it. Any product that came over during the upgrade from 2.2 to 2.3 cannot be edited. I do not have any custom attributes, but I am wondering if it has something to do with attributes. No errors on the broswer console log either. I just cant click any save function on the product edit page in 2.3 for products that were part of 2.2

Comment: Please make sure to assign all websites to stock before running the indexer. At least all websites with a product assigned